# Symantec Enterprise Vault not-compatible with XP x64

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, symantec

Is anybody know how to have Symantec Enterprise Vault 7.5.2.1862 functional with Windows XP x64? I have Office 2007 Pro Plus installed and when I open it up, I get the error message that valkyrie.dll cannot be charged.

I'm still searching for a x64 client or a fix for this dll file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer from Symantec. Enterprise Vault is not fully compatible with x64 based OS.

This is the email sent from Symantec;

> Hi David,
>
> My name is Steve from Symantec support. I've been assigned to case 411-XXX-7XX. In response to your question, at present Windows XP Professional 64 bit is not currently supported by Enterprise Vault. According to the latest compatibility guide: http://support.veritas.com/docs/276547  (pg 37) Windows XP Professional 64bit SP2 is currently in the (P)ending status.
>
> This certainly does not mean that it will not work for you, it just means that Symantec's engineering has not made a final determination as to whether it would work 100% properly.
>
> Please let me know if you have any further questions or concerns or if this case can be closed.
>
> Regards,